# How to delete an already written character in C++ console

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a C++ program to read a password.
I made the program to cout `*`, not the characters I write but my problem is when I want to delete character because they're wrong.
**Example:**
My constant password is `12345`
If I enter `1235`  the program will show `****` and I have to delete the last character. It's simple to remove it from the string but I want the last `*` to disappear from the console just as it happens when you introduce you windows password.
 Is it possible? If it is, can someone explain how?

Comment: The real question is how to delete UTF8 glyphs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Outputting the backspace character '\b' may help to move the output point back.

Specifically, outputting the string "\b \b" should blank out the last character output.

Comment: `\b` fails on macos(10.14.6)

Answer (score 5):

```
printf("\b ");
```

This statement surely works because after the cursor goes one character back and space given in above **printf** statement will overwrite the printed character on console output.

Answer (score 2):

When I am writting to console using putch function ( from conio.h ) to simulate backspace key
simple

```
std::cout << '\b';
```

or

```
printf("\b ");
```

not works
I have to write:

```
cout << '\b' << " " << '\b';
```

or

```
putch('\b');
putch(' ');
putch('\b');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try backspace \b or erase the whole line and print it again.

Answer (score 0):

Sipmly write the `'\b'` character to stdout `std::cout<<"\b"`. If you are using cpp or `printf("\b")` for pure C

Comment: you should make it as **std::cout<<"\b"**

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same thing recently, using the `\b` was** moving the cursor backward** but it was not deleting the char (or * ). I realize after that the next character you enter after `\b` is gonna replace the (character to be deleted). So, I came up with something like this

```
printf(“\b \b”);
```

using the `space key` after `\b` will replace the character to be deleted and again using the `\b` will take you one position back again (to the position where was incorrect character was, but this time the character will not be there) This way your output will look smooth. hope it will be helpful to you