# update text without printing a new line c

Tags: c, text

I am writing an alarm clock in c and I am trying to update a line of text without printing a new line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  time_t timer;
  char buffer[26];
  struct tm* tm_info;
  void delay(unsigned int mseconds)
  {
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
  }


  while(1){
    time(&timer);
    tm_info = localtime(&timer);



    strftime(buffer, 26, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tm_info);
    /*       puts(buffer);*/
    puts(buffer);

    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

This will print the time and the date and keep printing new lines  is there a way I could update everything on the same line?

Comment: Read `man puts`: This function always adds a new line at the end. You should use `fputs()`.

Comment: On some terminals the "carriage return" (CR) or `\r` will move the cursor to the start of the line. But it won't work everywhere.

Comment: Perfect opportunity to learn about [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Comment: Re ANSI escape sequences, I coincidentally just answered another question, and included all relevant code... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519752/scanf-equivalent-with-arrow-key-support-in-c/41520479#41520479

Comment: Escape Codes are my friend I found out about "\r".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are multiple ways to update within a terminal, [ANSI Escape Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) are very useful for this sort of thing. Examples can be found near the bottom of the page.

In addition, there exists the [ncurses library](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/), which provides a much larger variety of text and terminal manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

To not get a new line, use `printf()` instead of `puts()`.

To clear what is printed, you can do this after your `delay()` function, just before the end of your loop:

```
    int length = (int)strlen(buffer);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] ='\b';
    }
    printf(buffer);
```

The result isn't pretty, but it works.  I got that idea from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440272/how-to-delete-an-already-written-character-in-c-console).